# "SELECT TOP N" returns the wrong results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Supposing I have a table `foo` similar to:

```
ident int, primaryKey, auto_increment
someNumber int
statusId int
...
```

where the `someNumber` column is, except for a few special cases, equal to `ident`.  (in those special cases, `someNumber` is always equal to a previous `ident`).

I'm seeing problems which give the appearance that a query such as `SELECT TOP 10 ident, someNumber FROM foo WHERE statusId=@desiredStatusId ORDER BY someNumber` will return the wrong 10 records.  The records all have the correct statusId, but randomly there is one whose `someNumber` is way off.  For eaxmple:

```
ident        someNumber
-------      ----------
1234567      1234567
1234700      1234700
1234568      1234568
1234569      1234569
1234570      1234570
...          ...
```

What could be causing this query to intermittently return the wrong results?

Comment: Use [gist](https://gist.github.com/) to post a script with the `CREATE TABLE` statement, `INSERT` statements to populate the table, and the `SELECT` that is returning incorrect results. Chances are we'll immediately be able to find the problem or, even better, [you'll see it yourself](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RubberDucking).

Comment: The query is used directly by my application.  It is not used as a subquery, view, derived table, etc.  We have used it many times a day for several years and have heard of no such problems until very recently.  As such, I believe this problem is rooted in something environmental, and I am almost certain the database has not received proper maintenance in a very, very long time (if ever).

Answer (score 5):

A corrupted index could do it.  Have you run DBCC CHECKDB against that database?

Comment: Not yet.  I'm a developer, not a DBA, and I'm coming at this from a standpoint of explaining why the system I wrote on top of the database is suddenly screwed up.

This database is several years old.  I helped develop it, but was never granted the authority to maintain it.  I sincerely doubt that a competent DBA ever got anywhere near it.

My boss looked at the execution plan for this query and found that the index used by it was 100% fragmented.  We have made no code changes related to the query since before it messed up, so I thought it might be related to indexes.

Comment: @sworisbreathing fragmented<>corrupted and based on the information you've given, no code changes could produce this sort of effect. I'm not sure from your comment whether you are able to take Brent's advice or not, can you clarify?

Comment: I'm not able to run `dbcc checkdb` yet.  I don't own the database, so there's a bit of red tape involved in letting me perform maintenance tasks on it.

Comment: @sworisbreathing ok, perhaps you should point the DB owners here as I'm sure they'd like to know if there is even the possibility of corruption - I know I would

Comment: I have not run `dbcc checkdb`, but I did find a nightly  job defined on the server which the DB owners had apparently created.  Step 1 runs `DBCC CHECKDB ('DB Name') WITH NO_INFOMSGS` on every database on the server.  Step 2 does a full backup on every database.

Comment: I don't understand why step 1 of the backup job exists.  It does not appear to be redirecting the output of `dbcc checkdb` anywhere.  Assuming it found a problem during the nightly job, would it continue on with the backups?

Comment: @sworisbreathing Depends on the setup of the job - in each step, you can choose whether you'd like to continue or stop based on that step's success or failure.

Answer (score -3):

looks like some one made an error while dml statement , other wise it shouldnt have given you that error. if you do a select statement and check the order of the number after 1234567 is 1234700 , then it is definitely insert statement error.